# Define rule alias in Happy

Tags: parsing, haskell, happy

I'm reading a language specification, and trying to write a parser for it. In places the specification uses multiple names for the same thing. I tried to copy this to the Happy grammar like so:

```
foo : ...whatever...
bar : foo { $1 }
baz : foo { $1 }
```

Unfortunately, this causes Happy to flip out and start whining about "reduce/reduce conflicts". Basically, the problem seems to be that when it sees a `foo`, it doesn't know whether to reduce it to a `bar` or a `baz`. The truth is of course that *I don't care*, because they're all identical. But it still upsets Happy — which is linguistically ironic if nothing else.

(I'm also slightly scared that if I have a rule that mentions `bar` and another that mentions `baz`, the correct rule may fail to fire if the "wrong" reduction is picked. In other words, the parser will have a problem which is 100% impossible to ever debug.)

Is there some way I can tell Happy "wherever I say `bar`, just pretend I said `foo` and move on with your life"?

Obviously I *could* just use some external tool to do a textual find-and-replace, but I'd really prefer to not have to add yet *another* build step…